# Unity showing this error - Assets\Plugins\GitHub\Editor\UnityAPIWrapper.cs: error CS0103: The name 'UnityShim' does not exist in the current context

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I am using Unity 2019.2.2f1 and my project was built a long time with Unity 2017,2018. Now it is showing this error which is not resolving.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to ARCore and some basic packages.

**Steps to resolve:**

1. Import [ARCore SDK again](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/releases).(Assets >> Import Packages >> Custom Packages)

2. Use Window > Package Manager to install the "Multiplayer HLAPI" and "XR Legacy Input Helpers" packages. If it was already installed try removing and then reinstalling it again.